# putting dropdown for search in grid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a grid that has textboxes for search.  For the customer one I would like to add a down drop instead of a textbox.  Any suggestions?  Thanks

```
        <table id="customer_list" class="scroll jqTable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"></table>
        <!-- pager will hold our paginator -->
        <div id="customer_list_pager" class="scroll" style="text-align:center;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
        /* when the page has finished loading.. execute the follow */
        $(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery("#customer_list").jqGrid({
              url:'jq_customer_list',
              datatype: "json",
              colNames:['Customer','Application','Location','Product','id'],
              colModel:[
                {name:'Customer'},
                {name:'Application'},
                {name:'Location'},
                {name:'Product'},
                {name:'id', hidden:true}
              ],
              rowNum:1,
              rowList:[1,2,3,4],
              pager: jQuery('#customer_list_pager'),
              viewrecords: true,
              gridview: true
            });
            $("#customer_list").jqGrid('filterToolbar',{autosearch:true});
        });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add

```
{name:'location',stype:'select', searchoptions:   {value:':All;USA:USA;Canada:Canada;Carribean:Carribean;USPacific:USPacific;'}},
```

And you get your dropdown